# Valid observations based on conditions

Tags: r

I have the following data frame.

```
Student Class Jan_18_score Feb_18_score Jan_18_Weight Feb_18_Weight
(1)     Adam   1       NA            2           150           153 
(2)     Char   1       5             7           30            60
(3)     Fred   1       -7            8           NA            80
(4)     Greg   1       2             NA          80            40
(5)     Ed     2       1             2           60            80
```

For each month, for the observation to be valid it must have both a score and weight. Otherwise, both the score and weight are changed to 0.

The data should look something like this

```
Student Class Jan_18_score Feb_18_score Jan_18_Weight Feb_18_Weight
(1)     Adam   1       o            2           0           153 
(2)     Char   1       5             7           30            60
(3)     Fred   1       0            8           0            80
(4)     Greg   1       2             NA          80            0
(5)     Ed     2       1             2           60            80
```

I have tried the following (thank you if you have help me). But some of the values are not being changed to zero.

```
 # Separate score and weight columns 
 score_cols <- grep("score_", names(temp))  
 weight_cols <- grep("weight_", names(temp))

 valid <- is.na(temp[score_cols]) | is.na(temp[weight_cols])
```

I then use the new DF for calculations

```
temp2 <- aggregate(.~class, cbind(temp["class"], temp[score_cols] * temp[weight_cols]), sum)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678682/calculation-with-multiple-column-conditional-on-data-being-there). You haven't followed all the steps properly. Run these steps one by one and it works without any error on this new sample data as well. `score_cols <- grep("score", names(temp)); weight_cols <- grep("Weight", names(temp)); valid <- is.na(df[score_cols]) | is.na(df[weight_cols]); temp[score_cols][valid] <- 0; temp[weight_cols][valid] <- 0;` and then you can do `aggregate`

Comment: @ronakShar - Thanks Ronak apologies for the duplication. The mistake is mine - Can you please tell me how to add here the same thing if an observation is 0. Sorry valid <- is.na(df[score_cols]) | is.na(df[weight_cols])

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Instead of `NA` do you want to check for 0 instead? Something like `valid <- df[score_cols] == 0 | df[weight_cols] == 0` ?

Comment: @RonakShah - Quick note to say thanks for all your help with these questions! Sorry for so many.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad if my answers/comments were helpful to you :)